# Scala mutable map add

Tags: scala

I'm using a mutable HashMap with the MultiMap mixin and noticed that the `map.add` method is now deprecated:

```
val fieldTokenMap = new HashMap[String, scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int]] with MultiMap[String, Int]
// ...
fieldTokenMap add (token, docId)
```

I'm basically mapping a string or token to a list of ids.  Is there a different way I'm supposed to use the Map and MultiMap in Scala?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the deprecation message says, use `addBinding` instead.